# .NET CORE cant use AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding

Tags: c#, .net-core, encryption

I have a working c# sample code from my windows.
Then, I copy the function from there to my .net core for my mac.
bellow is my code

```
string DEFAULT_CIPHER_ALGORITHM = "AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding";
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(DEFAULT_CIPHER_ALGORITHM);
```

Then it throws bellow exception
exception.message :

> Message   "The type initializer for 'javax.crypto.Cipher' threw an
> exception."

exception.innerException

> InnerException    {System.TypeInitializationException: The type
> initializer for 'java.security.Security' threw an exception.  --->
> System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Void
> System.IO.FileStream..ctor(System.String, System.IO.FileMode,
> System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights, System.IO.FileShare,
> Int32, System.IO.FileOptions)'.    at
> IKVM.NativeCode.java.io.FileDescriptor.open(String name, FileMode
> fileMode, FileAccess fileAccess)    at
> java.io.FileDescriptor.open(String , FileMode , FileAccess )    at
> java.io.FileDescriptor.open(String , Int32 , Int32 )    at
> java.io.FileDescriptor.openReadOnly(String )    at
> java.io.RandomAccessFile.open(String , Int32 )    at
> java.io.RandomAccessFile..ctor(File file, String mode)    at
> java.util.zip.ZipFile..ctor(File file, Int32 mode, Charset charset)
> at java.util.zip.ZipFile..ctor(File file, Int32 mode)    at
> java.util.zip.ZipFile..ctor(String name)    at
> IKVM.Internal.VirtualFileSystem.Initialize()    at
> IKVM.Internal.VirtualFileSystem.GetVfs…

My imported dependencies :

```
IKVM.OpenJDK.Charsets
IKVM.OpenJDK.Core
IKVM.OpenJDK.Security
IKVM.OpenJDK.Util
IKVM.Runtime
```

How can I solve this issue? Thank you

Comment: **Read the exception message**: The exception has nothing to do with AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding.

Comment: It looks like IKVM doesn't support .NET Core (and .NET 5+) on Mac: it seems to have hard references to .NET API members that aren't available outside .NET Framework 4.x on WIndows.

Comment: IKVM hasn't been updated since 2018, and (as of July 2022) its website ( https://www.ikvm.net/ ) is inaccessible. There are forks on GitHub, but overall I'd say you're SOL. Why are you using IKVM and the Java API anyway...? If you want to open an AES-encrypted zip file then use DotNetZip

Comment: it is not for the zip file. Im trying to encrypt and decrypt a text, based on "AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding" in .net core

Comment: Then why aren't you using `System.Security.Cryptography.Aes` ?

Comment: @Dai thx. you made my day. couldnt find about that clue at all, When I typed .net core and aes encryption, its only IKVM result that is shown in here. now I can encrypt and decrypt aes successfully. cheers